# ¿Cómo redirigir una página con HTML?

Tags: html

¿Cómo puede configurarse una página de HTML básico para que cuando se cargue redireccione a otra página?

> <sub>Esto es una traducción de [Redirect from an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5411538/1983854)</sub>

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5411538

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incluye la siguiente línea en la sección `<head>` de la página:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Donde el parámetro `url` debe contener la página a la cual quieres redigir.

Además, para los navegadores antiguos en los que lo indicado arriba no funcione puedes añadir un enlace así:

```
<p><a href="http://example.com/">Redirección</a></p>
```

Que se mostrará como:

[Redirección](http://example.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar una función de `JavaScript`, para que redirecione apenas cargue la página.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function redirect() {
            window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
        }
        window.onload = redirect;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
</html>
```